# Nightwatch: wait for new email from gmail

Tags: javascript, automation, gmail, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am needing to use Nightwatch to wait until a new email is received from Gmail containing a temporary password. Sometimes the email is received within seconds, and it's easily obtainable, but sometimes it will take a little long and I'm needing to implement some sort of logic to wait until it's received. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is vital to my future test cases! Thanks

I have tried waiting for the class that Gmail has for new emails to be visible to no avail. It seems like I would need a wait until class changes to kind of method to get the results as the email will always be the first item in the emails

Comment: You have to do this via the browser?  A nodejs implementation using imap would be a lot easier! https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap

Comment: Hmm I will look into using that, thank you for the comment!

Comment: Just looking at our library, we actually used this one, was a bit easier to follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap-simple